# Wireless Network Shutdowns When Wired Connection is Active -- Was Working

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I have a Dell Latitude E5550 running Win7 64-bit that I use at work in a Dell advanced docking station.  Prior to yesterday, when docked and connected to a CAT 5 cable, the LAN connection would connect to the office network and the WLAN would connect to the office SSID and both adapters would work and be active.  Both IPs would ping from other computers.  This was working yesterday morning and the LAN port on the laptop or docking station all worked fine and coexisted w/ the WLAN on the laptop.

At some point yesterday, this started:

The WLAN will not connect to the office SSID when the docking station LAN or laptop LAN port are connected to the CAT 5 cable.  Nor can I browse for active wireless SSIDs.  Once I disconnect the LAN port or disable it, the WLAN will immediately connect to the office WLAN and will allow me to see active SSIDs.

I have checked BIOS power settings for the WLAN to auto disable when LAN is active and that is disabled.  The metric and priority order has not changed.  The LAN had higher priority already.  I removed the WLAN device from Device Manager and let Windows find and install again but that did not help.

Any ideas?  I have found a couple similar posts w/o resolution on here and other places.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  I had loaded a VPN client to a site and evidently the WiFi turnoff w/ active Wired Ethernet was part of the site protocol.  After removing the VPN client, WiFi and Wired now both coexist as before w/ active network connections.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue once. The red flags are:

1. It was working and at some point stopped
2. If I understand correctly, when ETH is connected, WLAN is completely unusable, not partially unusable.

In my case, it got solved by uninstalling the driver and then letting the drivers install automatically (i.e. Windows update).

Had to do it again about 8 months later. 
Still have no idea why...

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Tried that yesterday and it looked like it might work but all I got from it was that it lost all my defined Wireless Networks.